# doctest expected True, got True

Tags: python, doctest

doctest is hard to control. I encontered a problem like that

function

```
from collections import namedtuple

Match = namedtuple('Match', ['token_string', 'normalised_token',
                     'brand_name', 'brand_id',
                     'score'])


def make_match(tokens, normalised, brand, score):
"""
Examples:
>>> make_match('Jack Jones','JackJones',('Jack Jones','X023'),0.6)==Match('Jack Jones','JackJones','Jack Jones','X023',0.6)
True 
>>> make_match('Jack Jones','JackJones',('Jack Jones','X023'),0.6)==('Jack Jones','JackJones','Jack Jones','X023',0.6)
True
>>> match=make_match('Jack Jones','JackJones',('Jack Jones','X023'),0.6)
>>> match.token_string=='Jack Jones'
True
"""
return Match(token_string=tokens,
         normalised_token=normalised,
         brand_name=brand[0],
         brand_id=brand[1],
         score=score)
```

but got an error

```
Failed example:
make_match('Jack Jones','JackJones',('Jack Jones','X023'),0.6)==Match('Jack Jones','JackJones','Jack Jones','X023',0.6)
Expected:
    True 
Got:
    True
```

---

1 items had failures:

Isn't Expected matched exactly Got ?
Thank you very much
   1 of   4 in utilization.make_match
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.

Answer (score 6):

You have trailing whitespace on the line that specifies the expected return value, so `doctest` is really comparing the string `"True "` to actual returned value of `True`.

Comment: Or the file EOL is Windows (\r\n) and you are testing under Linux (\n)